# d3 liquid chart bugs

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've stripped out some code to leave just the square water chart itself. This is based on d3v3 version of the water gauge. How do you turn it into a bar/rectangle shape - instead of a square?

http://bl.ocks.org/brattonc/5e5ce9beee483220e2f6

//current jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/141/

so the parts I feel need to be modified are

```
    // The clipping wave area.
    const clipArea = d3.area()
        .x(function(d) { return waveScaleX(d.x); } )
        .y0(function(d) { return waveScaleY(Math.sin(Math.PI*2*config.waveOffset*-1 + Math.PI*2*(1-config.waveCount) + d.y*2*Math.PI));} );

        clipArea
            .y1(function(d) { return (fillCircleRadius * 2 + waveHeight); } );
            //.y1(function(d) { return (config.height - (fillCircleRadius * 2) + waveHeight); } );
```

and

```
            fillGroup.append("rect")
                .attr("x", radius - fillCircleRadius)
                .attr("y", radius - fillCircleRadius)
                .attr("width", fillCircleRadius * 2)
                .attr("height", fillCircleRadius * 2)
                //.attr("height", config.height - (fillCircleRadius * 2));
```

---

I had an old bar chart variant working here.. maybe something from this can help - anyone good at reverse engineering this.. how to do clip paths properly etc...

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1860/

Comment: Please, make your question more specific. It is not clear what do you want to be done.

Comment: How do you turn it into a bar/rectangle shape - instead of a square?

Comment: This is the closest I've got - a giant square that gets clipped. http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/145/